# How do I "denormalize" data in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using a neural network to predict how expensive a box will be to ship given the various sizes of the objects that go into them.

I'm normalizing all my data to make everything fit between 0 and 1, but how do I reverse the normalization so I can view my data set and see how close it is?

Here's what I have so far for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to reverse the normalization, but instead join the normalized version of the dataset with the original version after you apply `Score Model`.

The `Join Data` module should work if you have a key column, otherwise just use `Add Columns`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I reverse normalization on the predicted prices? Right now they're between 0 and 1, too. I suppose I could do the following calculation: (predicted normalized price)*(original price)/(normalized price). Or is there a better way?

Comment: Wait, so you're also normalizing the prices before training? I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Got it -- so no normalizing the labels. That makes sense.